# Copy files to a folder as Links

Tags: macos, terminal, cp

I'm trying to create a structured backup folder of links to the original files to facilitate drag and drop into a transfer client without having to copy the files again. I've alreast got this bit of code working that creates an actual folder of changed files

```
# user vars
srcDir=/Volumes/RAID/SRC/
destDir=/Volumes/RAID/DST/
destSuff=_SV_CB_EDITS

#do code
dateNow=$(date +"%y%m%d")
destDir="${destDir}${dateNow}${destSuff}"
echo "${destDir}"

(cd "$srcDir" && find . -type f ! -name '*.bak' -mtime -16h -print0) |
    while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' filepath; do
        mkdir -p "$(dirname "$destDir/$filepath")"
        cp -a "$srcDir/$filepath" "$destDir/$filepath"
    done
```

From what I have read, using `-al` instead of `-a` would work but it doesn't seem macOS version supports that.

Any help would be great

Comment: Maybe you should use [ln](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ln.1.html) ? This also works on macOS. (some extra info here: [How can I create a symbolic link in Terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115646/how-can-i-create-a-symbolic-link-in-terminal) )

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @Luuk